# Selenium IDE - Select checkbox on table row

Tags: css, selenium

I'm using Selenium IDE and I have a table where it has many rowns and columns. Each row has its own checkbox to select this row.

I was using this command to search for a specific row:

```
css=tr:contains('US Tester4') input[type="checkbox"]
```

But the problem is that in this colum, I have some other similar words like "US Tester41", "US Tester42" ... and when I use this command, it selects the wrong row.

I thought if I replace this word "contains" for some other like "equals" or "exactly" would work, but it didn't (I don't know the sintax).

Any ideas?

Follow the screenshot:
http://oi41.tinypic.com/2ake9hw.jpg

Comment: I would *highly* suggest against using the CSS `contains` selector. Can you provide another one?

Comment: provide what? sorry, I'm new on this CSS and Selenium world :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Selenium IDE, but with the selenium webdriver I would use an xpath. So I guess something like this will work for you:

```
xpath=//tr[td[3][text()='US Tester4']]//input[@type='checkbox']
```

Comment: It didn't work (I'm doing something wrong for sure) ... here's a screen for make it easier: http://oi41.tinypic.com/2ake9hw.jpg

Comment: Based on your screenshot I updated my answer. It's hard to get the precise xpath without the code. Maybe you can put the table content on jsfiddle. You can also test your xpath in Chrome using the developer tools. Try to run this on the console:  $x("//tr[td[3][text()='US Tester4']]//input[type='checkbox']") and see if you find any matches.

Comment: It worked for me:
//tr[td[3][text()='US Tester4']]//input[@name='uid']

Thanks!

Comment: Word of caution, defining it as in the third td makes it closely coupled to the table layout and adding or removing columns before it will affect it.  I try to avoid specifying the number in my tr and td selectors if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
//tr//td[.='US Tester4']//input[type="checkbox"]
```

against:

```
<table>
<tr><td>US Tester</td>input(type="checkbox")</tr>
<tr><td>US Tester4</td>input(type="checkbox")</tr>
<tr><td>US Tester41</td>input(type="checkbox")</tr>
<tr><td>US Tester412</td>input(type="checkbox")</tr>
</table>
```

It matched the second element.

Comment: It worked for me:
//tr[td[3][text()='US Tester4']]//input[@name='uid']

Thanks!

Comment: It isn't a good idea to hard code in the positions of the tags i.e. td[3] as it does not make the xpath dynamic. If another table row was to be added to this page the element could potential not be found using that xpath.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

`xpath=(//input[@name='uid'])[2])`

The 2 being the order of elemets

Comment: It worked for me:
//tr[td[3][text()='US Tester4']]//input[@name='uid']

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with the IDE but I have used the Webdriver before. If possible I would use this xpath.

```
xpath = "//td[.= 'US Tester4']//previous-sibling::td//input[@type = 'checkbox']"
```

This should locate only one element on screen. Using previous-sibling and following-sibling is very helpful when you haven't got a good enough identifier on the exact element you want to find. In your case the  which contains the checkbox hasn't a good identifier where as the  after has text which you could match using the '=' operator. You just need to use the 'previous-sibling' to find the  with the checkbox